# Ler arquivos .bat java

Tags: java

Alguém poderia me tirar uma duvida, como faço para ler e editar um arquivo .bat pelo java, no caso eu tenho um arquivo .bat que quero abrir ele em .txt para alterar, o método abaixo é oque estou utilizando

```
public void editarArquivo() throws SQLException, IOException{
    DirControle dir = new DirControle();
    String directory = dir.selectedDir_CB().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad "+directory+"\\"+getPasta()+"\\"+getArchive());
}
```

onde directory é o caminho do meu arquivo o getPasta() é uma pasta antes do arquivo e o getArchive() o arquivo em si

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O java é indiferente a extensões de arquivos e sim, so ao seu conteúdo, e um arquivo Bat é um texto, então para você escrever um arquivo de em Java, poderia fazer assim:

```
//Essa pasta é relativa ao lugar de execucao do programa.
File file = new File("diretorio/minha-saida.bat");//Como eu disse, é so texto
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

writer.write("1 1 1 1 1 \n");
writer.write("2 2 2 2 2 \n");
writer.write("3 3 3 3 3 \n");
writer.write("4 4 4 4 4 \n");
writer.write("5 5 5 5 5");

writer.flush(); //Cria o conteúdo do arquivo.
writer.close(); //Fechando conexão e escrita do arquivo.
```

Para ler, uma ideia seria:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
String data = null;
while((data = reader.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(data);
    //imprime o conteúdo, mas você poderia fazer outras
    //coisas com a variável data como salvar numa string que 
    //representa o arquivo etc.
}
fileReader.close();
reader.close();
```